# How do I show a diff in GitHub for files perceived as 'binary'?

Tags: git, github, diff

I have been trying to create my own mods for The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt in its proprietary scripting language, [Witcher Script](https://witcher.gamepedia.com/Witcher_Script), which has `.ws` extension.

I have created a Git repo to track these changes, and I have updated both `.gitattribute` and `.git/config` files so that I can see `git diff` results on CLI:

1. `.gitattribute`:

```
*.ws text
*.ws diff=localizablestrings
```

2. `.git/config`:

```
[diff "localizablestrings"]
        textconv = "iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8"
```

However, when I reach my repo on GitHub and try to see the changes I've done, I get this:
[image]

Is there any setting on GitHub that I have to update so that GitHub can show the commit changes as text?

Comment: I'm pretty sure github doesn't execute arbitrary commands in your gitattributes on your behalf. If anything, they might be able to consider some alternative specification.

Comment: @JoachimSauer yeah, I'm pretty sure about that too; but I was wondering if there was any setting I could use to make GitHub show these files. I think I will specify it in my OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Joachim Sauer mentioned in the comments, this isn't possible.  A file in UTF-16 is considered binary because it almost certainly contains NUL bytes.  Part of the reason is because GitHub needs to actually render the diff, and things that aren't valid UTF-8 can't be rendered as-is in the page.

Note that the textconv commands are loaded into your config and not the repo, and as such, nobody else even has a copy of them.  That's because running commands automatically based on the repository would be a colossal security risk, since someone could easily execute arbitrary code based on a malicious command.

If these files are really text files, just in UTF-16, consider instead storing them in UTF-8 and checking them out into the repository as UTF-16.  You can do this with something like one of the following:

```
*.ws text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16
# If you need the non-standard variant that's always LE with BOM:
*.ws text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16LE-BOM
```

Note that if you need the line endings to be CRLF, you can add `eol=crlf` as well.

If you do that, then run `git add --renormalize .`, then things should render properly in GitHub.

Comment: That's actually a pretty neat workaround, I didn't know of this setting!